# Rectangle select in Pinta freezes with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: pinta

I've always found Pinta far simpler to use to crop the occasional photo under Ubuntu 16.04 but I've just found, now that I'm under Ubuntu 18.04 that I can no longer do a rectangle select as it freezes almost immediately when "pulling" the "dotted rectangle" to where I want it.
I do receive a mask asking me whether I want to send the problem off to which I reply yes but is there anything I can do to make Pinta usable again?

Comment: I've tried re-sizing .jpg images with Pinta too and it "froze". I've now switched to Krita.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears it could be a bug affecting multiple users with Pinta: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pinta/+bug/1791916

I can verify this happens on KDE as well, so it's likely not specific to those distros, here is a crash log:

https://gist.github.com/krisives/4ad0953bc483f0883dd98c834c514964

If you don't care about Pita in specific you can try Krita.

I downloaded the code from GitHub (https://github.com/PintaProject/Pinta) and installed the latest MonoDevelop (https://www.monodevelop.com/download/) and opened the `Pita.sln` file and ran it using that in a debugger in an effort to find the error, but it doesn't happen in that build - which the About dialog says is version 1.7. This could mean:

- They fixed this bug in 1.7 - although I don't know if that's released yet
- The bug doesn't occur during a Debug build of the project
- Updating some other packages when installing the MonoDevelop PPA fixed a lower-level bug that existed in Mono or another system library

You can try 1.7 using their "Daily builds PPA" here:

https://launchpad.net/~pinta-maintainers/+archive/ubuntu/pinta-daily